# exec git command refuses to redirected to file in Go

Tags: go, io-redirection

I am trying to invoke a git log from go and redirect the output to a given file.

```
cmdArgs = []string{"log", "--numstat", "--reverse", fmt.Sprintf("%s..HEAD", "89c98f5ec48c8ac383ea9e27d792c3dc77fa6240"), `--pretty="format:=%P %H %an %ae %ad %at %s %b"`}

cmdArgs = append(cmdArgs, ">> "+workingDir+"/logs/"+repoName+".log && cat "+workingDir+"/logs/"+repoName+".log")

cmd := exec.Command("git", cmdArgs...)
cmd.Dir = workingDir + repoName

var out bytes.Buffer
var stderr bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &out
cmd.Stderr = &stderr
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("git", strings.Join(cmdArgs, " "), "in", workingDir+repoName)
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + stderr.String())
    panic(err)
}
```

fails with

```
git log --numstat --reverse --pretty="format:=%P %H %an %ae %ad %at %s %b" 89c98f5ec48c8ac383ea9e27d792c3dc77fa6240..HEAD  > /someplace/xx-tmp.log && cat /someplace/xx-tmp.log in /someplace
exit status 128: fatal: ambiguous argument ' > /someplace/xx-tmp.log && cat /someplace/xx-tmp.log: unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Executing the command in bash directly poses no problem.

Comment: `execv`-family syscalls don't honor shell operations -- if they did, you couldn't pass data with those literal symbols.

Comment: Which is to say -- what you need to pass here is equivalent to what you'd pass to the syscall interface, not what you'd pass to a shell.

Comment: Or execute the command line with a shell.

Comment: @phd, ...yes, but doing that takes some care to avoid security bugs. I'm working on an answer that does so, but it takes a minute to get the details right.

Comment: Right. But making the redirect yourself is also hard with all those `open` and `dup2`…

Comment: Just assign an *os.File to Command.Stdout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go's `cmd.Run()` acts similarly to the C `fork()` and `exec()` process for starting a new program. This *doesn't* implicitly invoke a shell -- which is, from a security perspective, an extremely good thing; unnecessary shell invocation often leads to command injection vulnerabilities.

If you *want* capabilities that a shell can add -- here, redirection and compound command syntax -- but want to avoid the security risks, pass your data out-of-band from code:

```golang
cmdArgs = []string{
  "-c",                      // tells interpreter that script is next argument
  `outfile=$1; shift; "$@" >"$outfile" && cat "$outfile"`, // script to execute
  "_",                                                     // this is $0
  workingDir+"/logs/"+repoName+".log",                     // $1, becomes outfile
  "git", "log", "--numstat", "--reverse",                  // remaining args are in "$@"
  fmt.Sprintf("%s..HEAD", "89c98f5ec48c8ac383ea9e27d792c3dc77fa6240"),
  "--pretty=format:=%P %H %an %ae %ad %at %s %b"
}

cmd := exec.Command("sh", cmdArgs...)
```

The above is equivalent to the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#      ^^- not /bin/bash; this only guarantees support for POSIX syntax

outfile=$1                 # assign first positional argument to variable "$outfile"
shift                      # rename $2 to $1, $3 to $2, etc
if "$@" >"$outfile"; then  # run remaining arguments as a single command, stdout to outfile
  cat "$outfile"           # if that succeeded, then cat our "$outfile" to stdout
fi
```

Note that I removed the literal quotes from inside `--pretty=`. That's because when you run the command in a shell, those quotes are treated as syntax *by the shell* -- an instruction not to split on the spaces within the format string. Here, there is no shell parsing that string as code; if we left the quotes in, they would become a literal part of your format string.

---

The above being said, there's no good reason to use a shell for any of this. You can do the redirection in native Go trivially:

```golang
cmdArgs = []string{
  "log", "--numstat", "--reverse",
  fmt.Sprintf("%s..HEAD", "89c98f5ec48c8ac383ea9e27d792c3dc77fa6240"),
  `--pretty=format:=%P %H %an %ae %ad %at %s %b`}
cmd := exec.Command("git", cmdArgs...)
cmd.Dir = workingDir + repoName

outputFile, err = os.OpenFile(workingDir+"/logs/"+repoName+".log",
                              os.O_APPEND | os.O_CREATE | os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
if err != nil { panic(err) }
defer outputFile.Close()

cmd.Stdout = outputFile
```

...and then run the `cat` as a separate `exec.Command` instance (if you have a good reason not to just implement it in native Go).